# Create your own Docker (sub-)commands

Tags: docker

Things like Git allow you to create your own (2nd-level) commands by creating a script with the appropriate name and saving it in the appropriate place (anywhere in your PATH if I recall correctly).  So you could have

```
$ git my-cool-command
```

if you wanted.

Is there a way to do such things with Docker?  <del>Google</del> [DuckDuckGo doesn't return anything useful](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=create+your+own+docker+commands).

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping someone else has a better answer, using a "docker-approved" officially supported approach that is not such a kludge, but here's an approach that should work if nothing else appears.

Write your own function named `docker`.  It should take precedence over anything in your PATH.

The function should take the first argument passed into it (we'll use `foo` as an example) and check whether a `docker-foo` command exists in the PATH.  If not, it should just call the docker executable with all arguments, so your command would work as expected.  If there *is* a `docker-foo`, it should call that (*with* the hyphen) and all other arguments appended.

Comment: These are not Docker subcommands. These are your commands that obfuscate the use of Docker. What is wrong with just using docker-foo? How much is replacing that dash with a hyphen worth to you, because that effectively is the only benefit if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Moreover, if you make a really good docker-foo, why not create a pull request implementing 'docker foo'?

Comment: @qkrijger: absolutely!  But it's useful to be able to have a local playground that doesn't absolutely require modifying the Docker source just to play.  (Git's ability to do this may have been an accidental side effect of being composed of many distinct scripts, with only some things in the core executable.  I haven't looked to see if Docker is structured that way too.)

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing this with BASH scripts.  For example:

```

## ~/.bash_aliases

#### Kill all running containers.

alias dockerkill='docker kill $(docker ps -a -q)'

#### Delete all stopped containers.

alias dockercleanc='printf "\n>>> Deleting stopped containers\n\n" && docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)'

#### Delete all untagged images.

alias dockercleani='printf "\n>>> Deleting untagged images\n\n" && docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)'

#### Delete all stopped containers and untagged images.

alias dockerclean='dockercleanc || true && dockercleani'

```

Comment: These don't do what I'm asking for.  I want to be able to create my own Docker subcommands, ***like those you can create for Git***.  So the syntax (of what I type on the command line) needs to be of the form `docker some_command some arguments`.  I'm not asking for aliases to other existing Docker commands.